# R: if NA, replace the missing value by that from another column, based on condition, using the column names pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, purrr

I have the following issue: for one `Rating`, the values in the 3 numerical columns out of 6 are missing.

I would like the missing values to be replaced by the values from the cells that are situated to the left from the column with the missing values. *The column names have a clear pattern - they all end with  `PD1`, `PD2` or `PD3`, which can be used as id*.

**Example:** the value in the column `eePD1` is missing for the `Rating` 1C, Basic `Scenario` and CORP `Class`.
It should be replaced by the value in the column `wePD1` ONLY if the `Class` is CORP. (RETAIL `Class` should not be touched).

**I.e, the value in **eePD1=wePD1 if** the value in **eePD1 was NA** and **Class=CORP**.**

| Scenario | Rating | Class | we*PD1* | we*PD2* | we*PD3* | ee*PD1* | ee*PD2* | ee*PD3* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | 1C | **CORP** | 0.51 | 0.74 | 0.43 | **NA** | **NA** | **NA** |
| Basic | 2A | CORP | 0.41 | 0.01 | 0.23 | 0.37 | 0.06 | 0.81 |
| Basic | 2B | **RETAIL** | 0.68 | 0.48 | 0.71 | **NA** | **NA** | **NA** |

**Desirable result**: if value from the cell in the column starting from `ee` is `NA` *for the CORP `Rating` and any `Class` and `Scenario`*, replace `NA` with the value from the column starting from `we` and ending like the name of the column starting from `ee`, for example `PD1`, `PD2` or `PD3`.

| Scenario | Rating | Class | we*PD1* | we*PD2* | we*PD3* | ee*PD1* | ee*PD2* | ee*PD3* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Basic | 1C | **CORP** | 0.51 | 0.74 | 0.43 | **0.51** | **0.74** | **0.43** |
| Basic | 2A | CORP | 0.41 | 0.01 | 0.23 | 0.37 | 0.06 | 0.81 |
| Basic | 2B | **RETAIL** | 0.68 | 0.48 | 0.71 | **NA** | **NA** | **NA** |

Here is the reproducible code chunk:

```
df3=structure(list(Scenario = c("Basic", "Basic", "Basic", "Basic", "Basic"
    ), Rating = c("1C", "2A", "2B", "2C", "3A"), Class = c("CORP", 
    "CORP", "CORP", "CORP", "RETAIL"), wePD1 = c(0.51, 
    0.41, 0.58, 0.28, 
    0.68), wePD2 = c(0.74, 0.01, 
    0.28, 0.92, 0.48
    ), wePD3 = c(0.43, 0.23, 0.04, 
    0.62, 0.71), eePD1 = c(NA, 0.37, 
    0.96, 0.22, NA
    ), eePD2 = c(NA, 0.06, 0.29, 0.22, 
    NA), eePD3 = c(NA, 0.81, 0.85, 
    0.78, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

The second solution option would be count three columns to the left, but it is *not elegant or generalizable* in case I were to have more columns...

So far, I could find only a few `dplyr` examples that would replace the value to the one below/above, but not to the sides, or based on the clear column name pattern for the better generalizability like with `purrr` and `map2_int`.

Comment: The "tidy" way to approach this problem would to turn this into a a "replace the value above/below" problem by pivoting your data to a long format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only have those columns, something like this should suffice:

```r
df3$eePD1 <- ifelse(is.na(df3$eePD1) & df3$Class == "CORP", df3$wePD1, df3$eePD1)
df3$eePD2 <- ifelse(is.na(df3$eePD2) & df3$Class == "CORP", df3$wePD2, df3$eePD2)
df3$eePD3 <- ifelse(is.na(df3$eePD3) & df3$Class == "CORP", df3$wePD3, df3$eePD3)
```

Before:

```
  Scenario Rating  Class wePD1 wePD2 wePD3 eePD1 eePD2 eePD3
1    Basic     1C   CORP  0.51  0.74  0.43    NA    NA    NA
2    Basic     2A   CORP  0.41  0.01  0.23  0.37  0.06  0.81
3    Basic     2B   CORP  0.58  0.28  0.04  0.96  0.29  0.85
4    Basic     2C   CORP  0.28  0.92  0.62  0.22  0.22  0.78
5    Basic     3A RETAIL  0.68  0.48  0.71    NA    NA    NA
```

After:

```
  Scenario Rating  Class wePD1 wePD2 wePD3 eePD1 eePD2 eePD3
1    Basic     1C   CORP  0.51  0.74  0.43  0.51  0.74  0.43
2    Basic     2A   CORP  0.41  0.01  0.23  0.37  0.06  0.81
3    Basic     2B   CORP  0.58  0.28  0.04  0.96  0.29  0.85
4    Basic     2C   CORP  0.28  0.92  0.62  0.22  0.22  0.78
5    Basic     3A RETAIL  0.68  0.48  0.71    NA    NA    NA
```

If you have more columns which follow this pattern then you would probably want to generalise it. But for just three columns I'd just take this approach.

A more general solution:

```r
for (target in grep("ee", colnames(df3), value=TRUE)) {
  source <- sub("^ee", "we", target)
  df3[[target]] <- ifelse(
    is.na(df3[[target]]) & df3$Class == "CORP",
    df3[[source]],
    df3[[target]]
  )
}
```

Comment: Was racking my brain trying to remember what you did in your for loop solution.

Comment: Thank you so much `@datawookie`. The general solution is exactly what I was after!